# how to specify a column and row to acess csv file Python

Tags: python, csv

I have been trying to access a specific row and column using indexes and I am not able to. I want to be able to give it two int's to say what row and column I am trying to return

I am trying to find the max of a column and then in that row return a string in a different column but same row.

I have already been able to calculate the max but I do not know how to access a row and column individually.

I am not able to use pandas unfortunately 
 '''Return the station ID of the station that has the most bikes available.
    If there is a tie for the most available, return the station ID that appears
    first in stations.

```
Precondition: len(stations) > 0

>>> get_station_with_max_bikes(SAMPLE_STATIONS)
7088
'''
```

with open("stations.csv") as f:
        a1 = [row["num_bikes_available"] for row in DictReader(f)]

max_index = a1.index(max(a1))

Comment: Can you edit your question to add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Python's `csv` module isn't that great. I'd recommend using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to manipulate your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas is the way to go BUT if you can't do that for whatever reason then I suppose you could create a dictionary for each ID and then find the ID that corresponds to the max value in the dictionary.

I assume your data looks something like this:

```
ID  Bikes
A   100
B   225
C   600
D   700
E   300
```

Then you could use:

```
import csv

dct = {}

with open(r'your_file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        identifer = row[0]
        bikes = row[1]
        dct[identifer] = bikes

print(max(dct, key=dct.get))

#output

D
```

Comment: Hey sorry I updated my post, I am not able to use pandas unfortunately